# Strip HTML tags from libreoffice command line conversion

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I'm trying to convert a HTML file, on my linux server, to a TXT file. The thing is the conversion working fine but it keeps the HTML tags in it. Any command to strip all HTML tags in the conversion ?

```
libreoffice4.2 --headless --convert-to txt 2000.html 2000.txt
```

Opening it in a GUI Libreoffice is already stripping HTML when saving from HTML to TXT so there must be something to accomplish this in command line too.

Comment: I think I've found something using `sed` command with a regex formula to strip the content of the HTML file instead to using Libre Office. Will tell if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell LibreOffice which filter it has to use in order to perform the conversion (see http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/)

```
libreoffice4.2 --headless --convert-to txt:text 2000.html
```

Comment: Hum... That's the same command line that I do only that you didn't add the output filename. The HTML tags still be in the file after conversion so sorry, no good.

Comment: The other difference is the addition of ":text" after "txt". This tells LibreOffice to use the "text" filter, which actually takes care of removing the HTML tags.
As for the output filename, it is ignored by LibreOffice. It basically takes the name of the source file, replacing the extension according to the target filetype.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative might be to use [**pandoc**](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)